# OpenGL hadware overlay

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, overlay, hardware

How to make a hardware overlay in Qt 5.1?

This is what I have so far:

```
QGLFormat fmt;
fmt.setSamples(16);
fmt.setOverlay(true);

MainWidget w(fmt);
w.show();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

MainWidget::MainWidget(const QGLFormat &format, QWidget *parent)
: QGLWidget(format, parent)
{
    qDebug() << format().hasOverlay() ?
            "Hardware overlay is supported" : "No hardware overlay support";
    qDebug() << "OpenGL " +
        QString::number(this->format().majorVersion()) + "." +
        QString::number(this->format().minorVersion());
}
```

But it always returns false :(
OpenGL version is 4.3
Video card is GeForce GT 650M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardware Overlays are not a standard feature. No consumer grade GPU supports them (well, their hardware could, but the drivers don't). You need a Quadro or a FireGL GPU for hardware overlays to become available.

Comment: Is there any way to patch my video card driver to get overlay planes to work?

Comment: @Sh1ne: Theoretically yes. And indeed ages ago you could patch your drivers to offer Quadro2 functionality on a GeForce2. BT;DT. But with today GPUs I don't know of any patch to do this. But what exactly is it you need a hardware overlay for? Can't you simply render to two FBOs, which you composite on each other before SwapBuffers?

Comment: I need hardware overlay to prevent any other program from being able to take a screenshot/video of my program

Comment: @Sh1ne: Trying to prevent other programs taking screenshot of your program's content is futile; there's always a way to do it. Also OpenGL hardware overlays don't make things "disappear" to screenshot tools: In modern OS the graphics visible to the user is composited, which means, everything your program renders gets coalesced into a single framebuffer (hardware overlays including) and composited by the OS with all the other windows in one single picture. Modern screenshot tools tap into that compositing process.

Comment: @Sh1ne: Screenshot tools like FRAPS use DLL injection to hook into each program's rendering process and extract images at the source. Remote visualization server software taps into the GPU's screen buffer. And last but not least there are DVI/HDMI capture devices which simply capture the signal from the wire to the screen. Personally I'm using such a device for making screencasts and tutorials, as it's the least invasive and doesn't comsume system resources.