# Windows: how to bypass Desktop Window Manager and draw to front buffer directly?

Tags: windows, opengl, latency

I have a fullscreen application for which I need to minimize rendering latency (to a hdmi connected screen) as far as possible (every millisecond shaved off makes a difference).
If I understand correctly, Windows is automatically drawing window content to offscreen buffers, then composes it and then swaps the compositing buffer to the screen (double or even tripple buffered).

Using OpenGL, how can I bypass the Desktop Window Manager and render to the front buffer directly (no swapping either, I don‘t mind frame tearing - I want pixels on the screen as fast as possible)

Comment: Google for `directx overlay surface`

Comment: according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200763/opengl-hadware-overlay surfaces get rendered into the offscreen compositor too